# Need a formula to calculate quantity in one column based on values from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can anybody help me with a formula to calculate the total quantity required (right hand column) if the column on the left has the same values rather than manually filtering and summing up total?

[image]

Comment: If your quality values are only these, as seen in your screenshot, then maybe you should consider the nested IF statement as one of the options...
https://exceljet.net/formula/nested-if-function-example

Comment: You don't show what you want for results, but, if I understand you correctly, you could use a Pivot Table; SUMIF and various other formulas, or even Power Query.  What have you tried?

Comment: Looking at Ron's response, I agree adding a screen cap example of what you are looking for as a result would really help people make suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Say the data you are looking to do this with is EXACTLY what you show in your question and further, that the data resides in the range A1:B22.

In that case, the following formula would do nicely:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$22,  "="&UNIQUE($A$1:$A$22),  $B$1:$B$22)
```

Basically, it's a `SUMIF()` that uses `UNIQUE()` in the criteria parameter. That lets you automatically get the list you need in one step, no further work. The output will be a `SPILL` array, but that is presumably just what you want. Use a column to its left (also a `SPILL` array) with just the:

```
=UNIQUE($A$1:$A$22)
```

to give those results their proper labels.

Answer (score 0):

*This help you:*

**::Caveat::**

- *This works with all versions of excel.*
- *If you are using higher versions like Excel 2019, Office 365, then you may use the formula shown by @Jeorje.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Array (CSE) formula in cell K2:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$20, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($K$1:K1, $H$2:$H$20), 0)),"")}
  ```

*Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.*

- Formula in cell L2:

  ```
  =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$37=K2)*($I$2:$I$37))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$37=K2)*($I$2:$I$37)))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*